# Is there any object storage designed for multi-user with policy restrictions?

Tags: filesystems

Is there any OPEN SOURCE object storage supporting those features?

- Multiple users created by API
- Policies to restrict: Single file size in user space, user space size, maximum amount of files uploaded to given user space
- Access to storage by providing user token or login & password